# Is $\ln(-x)$ irrational and transcendental?

Tags: logarithms, irrational-numbers

When $x$ is not $0$ or $1$ and is algebraic, $ln(x) $is transcendental and irrational but since $$\ln(-x) = \ln(x) + i \pi$$ I was wondering if the same is true here for $\ln(-x)$ where $x$ is neither $0$ nor $1$ and is algebraic.

Comment: I don't understand.  How can a number be algebraic and transcendental?  I thought a number was transcendental if it wasn't algebraic over some field?

Comment: @Karl OP is saying: "when $x$ is algebraic and $\ne0,1$, then $\ln(x)$ is transcendental"

Comment: Oh OK. That makes sense.

Comment: @john doe I edited the question. I feel it reads better. Just check it's OK. Thanks